# Выполнния метода, при нажатии кнопки и выделения поля ввода

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо, что бы при выделении JTextField и нажатии кнопки(Enter, например), вызывался метод.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textField.addActionListener(evt -> {
    ...
});
```